# How to search between $n$ candidates from unknown position?

Tags: algorithms, searching

It might be involved more with search algorithm but I cannot think of any of them. Here is the problem:

> You are in a corridor that stretches infinitely in both directions. Your room is somewhere
>   along the corridor, but you don't know how far away or even in which direction it is. You won't know if you have reached your room until you are right in front of it. Design an algorithm that enables you to reach the door by walking at most $O(n)$ steps where $n$ is the (unknown to you!) number of steps between your initial position and your room.

The problem is, current position is in middle if I choose to go left and till end does not find my room, I must come back all the way until first position which is already n steps!

Comment: If you search by going 1 ahead then 2 back then 3 ahead then 4 back it will take at most $2n$ steps to reach room $n$ will it not?

Comment: 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... n = 2n-1 is in O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by running $1$ step right, then $2$ steps left, then $4$ steps right and so on.
Assume that you hit your room at step $1 + 2 + 4 + \dots + 2^{m-1} + k$, $2^{m-1} < k \le 2^m$. Then we have used
$2^{m} - 1 + k$ steps in total, and we are at
$$n = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (-1)^j 2^{j} + (-1)^m k = \frac{1 - (-2)^{m}}{3} + (-1)^m k.$$
Therefore $|n| \ge k - \frac{1}{3} 2^{m} - \frac{1}{3} > 2^{m-1} - \frac{2}{3} 2^{m-1} = \frac{1}{3} 2^{m-1}$. In particular $2^m - 1 + k \le 2^{m+1} - 1 < 12 |n|$, so we have used $O(|n|)$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why you said number of step is 1+2+4+⋯+2^m−1+k? k is between 0 and 2^m, but what is "k"? (I'm not very good in maths)

Comment: @Bernard: $k$ is just the number of steps we took after the last change of direction.

Comment: Where did you get (−1)^j2^j. Could you please explain it a little bit more.

Comment: @Bernard: $2^j$ is the step length and $(-1)^j$ alternates between $-1$ and $1$, giving the steps alternating directions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't know how did you get from ((−1)^j)*2^j to 1-(-2)^m/3?

Comment: @Bernard: This is a geometric sum. In general $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} x^j = \frac{1 - x^m}{1 - x}$. Here we have $x = -2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16582/discussion-between-bernard-and-j-j).

Comment: I am not really sure how you have made this statement. Is there any formula?|n| ≥k−(1/3) 2^m −(1/3) >2 ^ (m−1)−(2/3)2^(m−1)=(1/3)2^(m−1)

Comment: @Bernard: $(-1)^m k$ and $-(-2)^m$ have different signs and $k$ is larger than $2^m/3$. If we assume that $1/3$ is of opposite sign from $(-1)^m k$, we see that the smallest value $|n|$ can be is $k - (1/3) 2^m - (1/3)$. The rest is simply using the definition of $k$.